# (Android) Atempting to implement static Weakreference runnable

Tags: android, memory-leaks, runnable

Initially i set myself a simple task to make a function to execute with delay. At first i made a runnable and executed it with `new Thread(runnable).start();`, but i've read, that non-static inner classes can lead to memory leaks, so i tried to make `Runnable` as static.

I followed example in [Is this Runnable safe from memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694222/is-this-runnable-safe-from-memory-leak) and ended with this code:

```
public class ApproxManager {
    private Context mContext;
    private AlarmManager mAlarmManager;

    public ApproxManager(Context context){
        mContext = context;
        mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    }

    public void setPeriod(int type, long when, int extendCount){
        Intent i = new Intent(mContext, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
        long alarmtime = when;
        i.putExtra(RReminder.PERIOD_TYPE, type);
        i.putExtra(RReminder.EXTEND_COUNT, extendCount);
        i.setAction(RReminder.CUSTOM_INTENT_APPROXIMATE_PERIOD_END);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        new Thread(new WeakRunnable(mContext, alarmtime,pi)).start();
    }

    public void setAlarm(long alarmTime, PendingIntent pi){
        mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, pi);
    }

    private static final class WeakRunnable implements Runnable {
        private final WeakReference<Context> mContext;
        long mAlarmtime;
        PendingIntent mpi;

        protected WeakRunnable(Context context, long alarmtime, PendingIntent pi){
        mContext = new WeakReference<Context>(context);
        mAlarmtime = alarmtime;
        mpi = pi;

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Context context = mContext.get();
            if (context != null) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ApproxManager approxManager = new ApproxManager(context);
                approxManager.setAlarm(mAlarmtime,mpi);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am unfamiliar with inner classes and referencing, so despite my code appears to be working, i am not sure, if i have suceeded with my goal to avoid memory leaks. So i would appreciate if someone could look at my code.

Comment: Not really solution but you can greatly reduce memory leakage if you use AplicationContext instead of activity- that way even if leakage happen it won`t hold visual resources in the memory

Comment: Ahh, i see. So, if use ApplicationContext to instantiate my ApproxManager class, my parent activity will be garbage collected even if ApproxManager outlives the activity?

Comment: Yes if you use AplicationContext, ApproxManager won`t hold reference to the activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine IMHO. I think you have managed to successfully implement you runnable and protect yourself against a memory leak.

Non - static inner classes hold a implicit reference to the instance that created them. This means that, if you go with the non - static approach, you will be keeping a reference to a `ApproxManager` instance and this instance will not be garbage collected. The `ApproxManager` keeps a reference to the `Context` and `AlarmManager` instances and they won't be garbage collected neither and this is you memory leak.

Static inner classes don't hold any implicit references, but they can't access non - static members, so you are forced to provide all the needed dependencies so the class can do it's work. Using `WeakReference` you won't prevent eventual garbage collection of the variable, if there is need for one.